# Removal of .Net Framework 1.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, frameworks

I have a asp.net application which was developed using Visual Studio 2003 .Net Framework 1.0,1.1. And currently we migrated the source code to 2.0 Framework and then to 3.5 Framework.

Now our IT Team has recommended us to remove .Net Framework 1.0 from the server due to some Microsoft Vulnerability.

Kindly suggest if its ok to remove the 1.0 Framework and would the migrated application work without any problem after 1.0 Framework removal.

Comment: We don't know. Does your application use any deprecated features in 1.0? Does your application use any features that have changed behavior since 1.0? _You_ know answers to these questions. We don't.

Comment: This is a massive application and lots of code & libraries. And initially(years back) developed by some other developers. And the codebase has been migrated by us. But there were few parts in code that didnt require migration. Majorly in the Libraries. Is there a good way to trace this gaps.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to tell clearly if you are using Windows Server 2003. On all other Windows OS, you can go to Programs in Control Panel to uninstall .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1.
2. Before doing step 1, of course you can upgrade your ASP.NET applications to .NET 2 or .NET 4 by changing the ASP.NET runtime loaded by the application pool. That's purely IIS settings you should learn. Perform such migration testing in development or QA environment before any change in production. (If you already have done this step, simply execute step 1.)